# Print cell values for excel files

Tags: excel, scala, apache-poi

I am trying to load and read Excel files using a custom DSL at [Apache POI DSL](https://github.com/folone/poi.scala).

I want to provide Excel support for spark and for the purpose I am using Apache POI. I have found the above DSL repository in Scala. I am trying to find a way to read cells and print them using Scala.

```
object XlsLoader{
    def f1(): Unit ={
        val path = "/Users/shashi/data311.xlsx"
        val res = Workbook(path)
        val res1 = res.getOrElse(null)
        println(res1)

        println("one")

        val q = res1.map {
            x =>
                println("hello")
                println(x)
                println("sheetmap -- "+x.sheetMap)
                println("flatten -- "+x.sheetMap.toList)
                println("keys -- "+x.sheetMap.keys.toList)

                println("1he")
                x.sheetMap.keys.toList.foreach(n => println(n))
                println("2he")

                println("toString -- "+x.toString())
        }

        println("two")
        println(q)
    }
}
```

This is the output.

```
scalaz.effect.IO$$anon$7@1a8e246b
one
two
scalaz.effect.IO$$anon$7@34ccc2af
```

I want to find the internal structure of the sheet and print it. How do I do it ?

This is the excel file for your reference.

```
c1  c2
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400
5   500
```

Comment: Do you need some more specifics in the answer or you can accept it?

Comment: I accept the answer, couldn't upvote because of reputation. Now i need to convert this excel into dataframes, but that is out of the scope for this question, suggest any useful link if you have.

Comment: If you accept the answer, could you mark it as correct one please (with green tick)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was using the following dependency:

```
"info.folone" %% "poi-scala" % "0.18"
```

Now the only thing missing in your code is calling of `.run` and `.unsafePerformIO` (or more safe alternative of it).

Also I created a small **sample that would explain it step by step** and provide general structure of given `.xls` file to console, hope it will be useful:

```
import java.io.InputStream

import info.folone.scala.poi._

import scalaz.{-\/, \/-}

object ReadExcelFile {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val readResult = Workbook(xlsFile)
      .map(workbook => workbook.sheets)
      .run
      .unsafePerformIO()
    readResult match {
      case -\/(exception) => throw new RuntimeException("Could not read file", exception)
      case \/-(sheets) => sheets.foreach(printSheet)
    }
  }

  def printSheet(sheet: Sheet): Unit = {
    println(s"------------ ${sheet.name} ------------\n")
    sheet.rows.foreach(printRow)
  }

  def printRow(row: Row): Unit = println(row.cells.toList.sortBy(_.index).mkString(", ") + "\n")

  def xlsFile: InputStream = ReadExcelFile.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/test.xls")
}
```

The **output** is going to be like this:

```
------------ Sample-spreadsheet-file ------------

FormulaCell(0, "=A1+1"), StringCell(1, "1.7 Cubic Foot Compact "Cube" Office Refrigerators"), StringCell(2, "Barry French"), NumericCell(3, 293.0), NumericCell(4, 457.81), NumericCell(5, 208.16), NumericCell(6, 68.02), StringCell(7, "Nunavut"), StringCell(8, "Appliances"), NumericCell(9, 0.58)
```

As you can see it **prints cell types, contents and sheet name.**

Hope it helps!